# Object oriented design for InputStream.markSupported method

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm reading Elliotte Rusty Harold's *Java Network Programming*. In chapter2, I've read the text about `makrSupported()` method of `InputStream` class. The author explains that this method is not object oriented. Because the function for checking `mark()` available is not provided by separated type. How is the design to be more object oriented still supporting `mark()` and `reset()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a good object-oriented design, there is no need to ask an object if it supports a method like `mark` or not. Instead, the interface- or class type of your reference should tell you exactly which methods your code expects to be able to use.

A more object-oriented design would be along the lines of

```
class InputStream extends Object
{
  ...
  // no mark() nor reset()
}

class ResettableInputStream extends InputStream
{
  void mark() { ... }
  void reset() { ... }
}
```

The reason that Java isn't designed this way probably has historical reasons, such as that `InputStream` with `mark`/`reset` was already in widespread use when a new derived class was introduced that couldn't support `mark`/`reset` and a strong desire to not break all existing code.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But sometimes, I may need to handle a bunch of InputSreams mixed with InputStreams and ResettableInputStreams. Using `instanceof` operator seems worse than before. In that case, how can I write OOP code? Or how can I avoid this case?

Comment: @jyshin, if you don't need the `mark`/`reset` behaviour, then you can treat them all as plain InputStreams. No need for `instanceof`.

Comment: I would point out that promising functionality that doesn't exist is bad design generally, and good design of any sort will avoid it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Oh.. I got it. I think you mean use of `mark / reset` with `InputSteam`(in your design) is also bad. If I need `mark / reset`, I should do it with `ResettableInputStream` type. Did I get it right?

Comment: @jyshin, yes that is right. In fact, in my design, it would be impossible to use `mark`/`reset` on an `InputStream` without casting it to a `ResettableInputStream` first.